# Create step bar with change divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I´m trying to create a steps bar with html css and javscript vanilla and I want that when I click on my button 'next change' show other information. Now, I have done my step bar with all my logic but i don´t know how i can to do for change my div active.

My **html**

```
<div class="container"\>
<div class="progress-container"\>
<div class="progress_step" id="progress_step"\>\</div\>
<div class="circle active"\>\</div\>
<div class="circle"\>\</div\>
<div class="circle"\>\</div\>
<div class="circle"\>\</div\>
<div class="circle"\>\</div\>
</div\>
<div class="row justify-center"\>
<div class="col-8"\>
<div class="bg-white shadow rounded p-3 precontract_info"\>
@include('Commercial.partials.agent_data')

                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-dark mr-4" id="prev" disabled>Atrás</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-dark" id="next">Siguiente</button>
                 </div>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8 d-none">
             <div class="bg-white shadow rounded p-3 precontract_info">
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

my **css**

```
 @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Muli&display=swap");
    :root {
     --line-border-fill: #000;
      --line-border-empty: #e0e0e0;
    }
    
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .container{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .progress-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .progress-container::before {
        content: ""; /* Mandatory with ::before */
        background-color: var(--line-border-empty);
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 0;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        height: 4px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 0;
     }
    
     .progress_step {
        background-color: var(--line-border-fill);
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 0;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        height: 4px;
        width: 0%;
        z-index: 1;
        transition: 0.4s ease;
      }
    
     .circle {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #999;
        border-radius: 50%;
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        border: 3px solid var(--line-border-empty);
        transition: 0.4s ease;
        z-index:1
     }
    
     .circle.active_step {
        border-color: var(--line-border-fill);
     }
    
    .btn:active {
       transform: scale(0.98);
    }
    
    .btn:focus {
      outline: 0;
    }
    
    .btn:disabled {
       background-color: var(--line-border-empty);
       cursor: not-allowed;
     }
```

my js:

```
    const progress = document.getElementById("progress_step");
    const prev = document.getElementById("prev");
    const next = document.getElementById("next");
    const circles = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");
    
    let currentActive = 1;
    
    next.addEventListener("click", () => {
      currentActive++;
      if (currentActive > circles.length) currentActive = circles.length;
      update();
    });
    
    prev.addEventListener("click", () => {
      currentActive--;
      if (currentActive < 1) currentActive = 1;
      update();
    });
    
    const update = () => {
      circles.forEach((circle, index) => {
        if (index < currentActive) circle.classList.add("active_step");
        else circle.classList.remove("active_step");
      });
      const actives = document.querySelectorAll(".active_step");
      progress.style.width = ((actives.length - 1) / (circles.length - 1)) * 100 + "%";
      if (currentActive === 1) prev.disabled = true;
      else if (currentActive === circles.length) next.disabled = true;
      else {
        prev.disabled = false;
        next.disabled = false;
      }
    };
    
    let cb = document.getElementById('second_agent')
    cb.addEventListener('change', function (){
    
    let cb2 = document.getElementById('second_agent_block')
    if(this.checked){
      
      cb2.classList.remove("d-none");
    }else{
      cb2.classList.add("d-none");
    }

})
```

all this code does work. I can show my step bar with my data, but I want to change my active div when my next button was clicked.

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english.

I expecting that I can to change my active div and hide my old div.

Comment: Hiding a div without remaing space can you achive with `display:none;`. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69020870/remove-css-class-of-element the accepted answer to hide and show a div